# SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder - Apply differently to each row (ListFragment)

Tags: java, android, simplecursoradapter, android-listfragment

In my app, I pull 3 strings from an SQlite database to populate a ListView. In the listrow I have to TextViews and an ImageView.

The two TextViews are currently populated properly(with different text in each row). But, this is not the case for the ImageView, which I set using a ViewBinder. Namely, the image in each row all get the same color. How can i fix this? Do I need to extend SimpleCursorAdapter or something?

```
String[] from = {DbHelper.NAME, DbHelper.COMMENT, DbHelper.COLOR};
String[] column = {DbHelper.C_ID, DbHelper.NAME, DbHelper.COMMENT, DbHelper.COLOR};
int[] to = {R.id.listitem_title, R.id.listitem_summary, R.id.listitem_color};

Cursor cursor = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, column, null, null, null, null, null);

this.adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_set, cursor, from, to);

adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.listitem_color) {

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String color = "#ffffff";
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        color = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COLOR));
        }
        ((ImageView) view).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
         }
    });

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Namely, the image in each row all get the same color. How can i fix
>   this?

If you're going to use:

```
String color = "#ffffff";
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    color = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COLOR));
}
```

this will make the `color` point to the color present in the last row of the `Cursor` as you loop through the entire `Cursor`. Instead you'll want to simply get the `color` from the `Cursor`:

```
String color = "#ffffff";
color = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COLOR));
```

Comment: Excellent (also had to delete cursor.moveToFirst) Thanks man!

Comment: @Jakob Yes, the `Cursor` is already positioned pointing to the correct row, you just need to retrieve the data from it.